# Problem Spatial Awareness Display on IPAD when using MRTK and Azure spatial anchors

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ipad, mrtk, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm making App for IOS using MRTK3 and Azure Spatial Anchors following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/azure-spatial-anchors-tutorials/3-exercise-get-started-with-azure-spatial-anchors.
I was able to make APP for Hololens2.
When I build it for Ipad, Azure Spatial Anchors works correctly.But there is a problem with Spatial Awareness Display.
Places where spatially mapped become blacker and blacker.
Could you teach me how　to solve it?

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVU4y.jpg)

Windows 11
unity 2020.3.48
AR foundation 4.1.7
AR Core XR Plugin
AR kit 4.1.13
Mixed Reality Foundation 2.7.3
Azure Spatial Anchors Core , windows, ios 2.12

Mac Intel OS Venture
Ipad OS 17.3.1

First I made Unity project on Windows, then I changed it for IOS and built it by Mac.

I changed MRTKToolKit Camera setting then Update Script Defines
Project Setting  XR Plug-in Management ARKit

Player setting Uncheck Strip Engine Code
Filled Camera Usage Description
check Requires ARKit support

Assets/MRTK.Tutorials.AzureSpatialAnchors/Plugins/RestSharp  check IOS and ARKit

Answer (score 0):

Currently Spatial Mapping is exclusively supported by HoloLens devices. See: [Spatial mapping in Unity - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/spatial-mapping-in-unity?tabs=mrtk#device-support).

Additionally, to use Spatial Awareness, ensure your application is running on a device that provides environmental data (ex: Microsoft HoloLens). See: [Spatial Awareness System · microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/wiki/Spatial-Awareness-System#spatial-awareness-system-requirements).